# Removing reverse elements in a Python list

Tags: python, list

How do I remove all lists in list_a that is a reversed list of a previous list in list_a?

```
list_a = [[1,2,3],[5,4],[4,5],[3,2,1]]
```

should give

```
[[1,2,3],[5,4]]
```

Comment: Is this only reversed lists that laready exist or does order not matter at all?

Comment: if the list is mirrored: `list_a[:len(list_a)//2]`

Comment: What if the same list appears twice? Should the result contain both?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 4], [4, 5], [3, 2, 1]]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in l if tuple(x[::-1]) not in seen and not seen.add(tuple(x))]
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 4]]
```

Comment: This is only checking if the reverse is not in `seen`, not the original as well

Comment: Also, sorted() is not the same as reversed().

Comment: +1 though, this may be what OP wanted but not sure what OP wants for `list_a = [[3,2,1],[5,4],[4,5],[3,2,1]]`

Answer (score 2):

You may convert the results back to `list`s if you really need:

```
res, seen = [], set()
for x in map(tuple, list_a): # lists can't be hashed
    find = {x, x[::-1]}
    if not find.issubset(seen):
        res.append(x) # you may use res.append(list(x)) if you have to
        seen.update(find)


>>> res
[(1, 2, 3), (5, 4)]
```

note this is checking for duplicate items, as well as duplicate reversed items. If you only want the latter you can use the approach by [@AshwiniChaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212236/1219006)

eg. for

```
list_a = [[3,2,1],[5,4],[4,5],[3,2,1]]
```

this approach produces:

```
[[3,2,1],[5,4]]
```

while @Ashwini's approach produces:

```
[[3,2,1],[5,4],[3,2,1]]
```

I'm not sure which result you want

Answer (score 2):

A slightly cryptic, but in my opinion elegant way to achieve this is:

```
[v for k, v in enumerate(list_a) if v[::-1] not in list_a[:k]]
```

If you also want to remove duplicates, change to:

```
[v for k, v in enumerate(list_a) if v[::-1] not in list_a[:k] and v not in list_a[:k]]
```

Comment: This is `O(N^2)`, but you can make it a bit memory efficient if you use a generator expression : `if v not in (el[::-1] for el in list_a[0:k])`

Comment: No need for the second comprehension, simply `...if v[::-1] not in list_a[:k]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash for getting it done.

```
 a=[[1,2,3],[5,4],[4,5],[3,2,1]]
 d={};b=[]
 for i in a:
    try:
        d[str(i)]+=1
    except KeyError:
        d[str(i)]=0;d[str(i[::-1])]=0
        b.append(i)
 print b
```

**Output :**

```
[[1,2,3],[5,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to achieve this, would be the following.

we assume here that any one element can't appear more than once in the output list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list_a   = [[1,2,3],[5,4],[4,5],[3,2,1]]
list_out = []

for i in list_a:
  i_r = i[::-1] # reverse the element

  # check that it doesn't appear in the list, reversed or not... 
  if i_r not in list_out and i not in list_out:
    list_out.append(i)

print "out:  " + str(list_out)
```

if you just don't want the duplicates, but you want to remove the reversed elements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list_a   = [[1,2,3],[5,4],[4,5],[3,2,1]]
list_out = []

for i in list_a:
  i_r = i[::-1]
  if i_r not in list_out:
    list_out.append(i)

print "out:  " + str(list_out)
```

And comparing those two functions, with the following input:

```
list_a   = [[1,2,3], [5,4], [4,5], [3,2,1], [1,2,3], [5,4]]
```

output from first method:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 4]]
```

output from second:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 4], [1, 2, 3], [5, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are already somewhat optimized, this is a "naive" approach designed to be readable and understandable. It will be slower than answers using a set or dict, but this probably doesn't matter if your list size isn't huge:

```
list_a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
list_b = []
for item in list_a:
    if not list(reversed(item)) in list_b:
        list_b.append(item)
```

Comment: hint: `reversed(x)` is not a list.